# use es6promise to make remote call sequentially

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise, axios

I am trying to use es6 promise , to make two remote calls in sequence, 
here is my code

```
recordsCount(){
        let classInstance=this;
        let stateIns=this.state;
        return axios.post('/api/projectDocs/count',stateIns.gpSearch).then((response)=>{
            stateIns.totalRecords=response.data;
            classInstance.setState(stateIns);
        });

    }


loadGpDocs(start, end){
        let classInstance=this;
        let stateIns=this.state;
        stateIns.gpSearch.start=start;
        stateIns.gpSearch.end=end;
        return axios.post('/api/projectDocs/search',stateIns.gpSearch).then((response)=>{
            stateIns.data.gpDocs=response.data;
            classInstance.setState(stateIns);
        });
    }
```

code to call the two functions

```
classInstance.recordsCount().then(classInstance.loadGpDocs(0, 20).then(function () {
                stateIns.ready = true;
                classInstance.setState(stateIns);
            }));
```

first call the records count, this returns a axios promise , then load data, this return axios promise  then apply changes to UI.

Iam missing something, calls are not in sequence, please help   me understand promise, why this code is not   following sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will call the code in sequence, this is because we are using promise chaining to achieve "blocking". Since all returned promises initially start out in a `pending` state, each promise will be properly awaited and the next promise will not be called until the promise before it has a `fulfilled` state.

It will execute in the following order

1. Call `recordsCount()` and update `stateIns.totalRecords`
2. Call `loadGpDocs()` and update `stateIns.data.gpDocs`
3. Update `stateIns.ready`

   ```
   return classInstance.recordsCount()
     .then(() => {  // Wait for recordsCount() to be fulfilled
       // Notice that we are returning this promise
       // the next then() will wait until loadGpDocs is fulfilled
       return classInstance.loadGpDocs(0, 20);
     })
     .then(() => {
       stateIns.ready = true;
       classInstance.setState(stateIns);
     });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `loadGpDocs(0, 20)` is called **outside** of the promise chain

You could solve it by doing:

```
classInstance.recordsCount()
  .then(classInstance.loadGpDocs.bind(classInstace, 0, 20))
  .then(function () {
       stateIns.ready = true;
       classInstance.setState(stateIns);
   }));
```

Notice that `classInstance.loadGpDocs.bind(classInstace, 0, 20)` is returning a *function* with its arguments applied **without calling it**, so it gets executed inside the promise chain whenever `recordsCount()` promise is done